# UIAlertView color and background in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, uialertview

How can I change the color or/and the background of UIAlertView. Found examples in objective-c, dunno how to apply them in monotouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started, you probably need to tweak the image frame a bit to get it correct relative to your background image.

```
public class FooAlertView : UIAlertView
{
    UIImageView imageView;

    public FooAlertView()
    {
        this.Title = "Alert!";
        this.Message = "Puppies are cute...";
        AddButton("OK!");
        imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("Images/popover/popoverBg.png"));
    }

    public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        foreach(var uiview in this.Subviews) {
            if(uiview.GetType() == typeof(UIImageView)) {

                uiview.RemoveFromSuperview();

                this.AddSubview(imageView);
                this.SendSubviewToBack(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: something wrong... it shows the picture, but it's behind the blue frame. I need to change the background of that frame

Comment: no... not the background, better say tint. I want to keep that nice semi-transperent frame with nice rounded corners and beautiful border. I just need to change the color

Comment: Poor guy, I hate to give you more bad news today but the transparency, rounded corners and beautiful borders are just a flat image that Apple stuck in there behind a UIButton and a few UILabels. I edited the answer to reflect your use case.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to add new sub view with image. You can replace existing image in image view.

```
  public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        foreach (var uiview in this.Subviews)
        {
            if (uiview.GetType() == typeof(UIImageView))
            {
                UIImageView imageView = uiview as UIImageView;
                if (imageView != null) imageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/header.png");

            }
        }
    }
```